# Hugo won't let me list pages from a section, rejecting arguments?

Tags: javascript, hugo

`layouts/index.html`:

```
{{define "main"}}
{{ $products := .Site.RegularPages.ByTitle "Section" "products" }}
{{with .Params.banner}}
[...]
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  {{ range (where $products ) }}
                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
                  {{ end }}
[...]
```

Produces this error:

```
ERROR: executing "main" at <.Site.RegularPages.ByTitle>: wrong number of args for ByTitle: want 0 got 2
```

Okay, so let's try removing those two (necessary) arguments I guess?

```
{{ $products := .Site.RegularPages.ByTitle }}
```

Now, the error says:

```
ERROR: executing "main" at <where>: wrong number of args for where: want at least 2 got 1
```

What's going on here? The first bit of code works in my `layouts/header.html` just fine, but now Hugo seems to be confused.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a where statement.
$products is a variable

```
.Site.RegularPages.ByTitle <- isn't a value.
```

Therefore the errors are clear, no?

But to handle your original point:

Your halfway between assigning a variable and running a function.

So:

```
$products := .Site.RegularPages <- existing "Array/Map/Slice" assigned to a variable
```

.ByTitle is a parameter to pass to a function (I believe).

If you want that grouping organized by title-which would be a function to run before assigning to a variable.

Ranges through the regular pages by title like you want:

> ```
> {{range .Site.RegularPages.ByTitle}}
> {{ . }}
> {{ end }}
> ```

If you still want then an "array" sorted by title:
See docs:

```
https://gohugo.io/functions/where/ (which I find to be excellent) and 
https://gohugo.io/functions/sort/#readout
```

You would use Sort. You could also just do this:

```
{{range where .Site.RegularPages.ByTitle "Section" "products" }}
 {{ . }}
{{ end }}
```

Or more specifically:

```
{{ $product := where .Site.RegularPages.ByTitle "Section" .Section }}
```

Summary:
To answer your question:
Your code isn't working because you are mixing assigning a variable with running a function.

You have almost a where statement in the assignment of the variable. That's why the errors you are receiving.

additional notes:

As I don't have access to your repo, I don't really know what you are trying to do, I would suggest you use the above docs to help you out.

The "earlier error" I think you are trying to resolve is this "with" statement of .Params.Banners as you are "dropping context" I do believe that their is faulty logic there.

However, if you still want to get around this, use "sort" to sort the value or $products (assigning it the Regular pages with the where statment).